# Fade out animation with shade

Tags: android, animation, fadeout

I'm using a fade out animation to exit my fragment and it's working just fine. What I want to do now is make the background color of the exiting fragment grey like the animations of the AlertDialog. This is my anim file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
         android:duration="300"
         android:fromXScale="1.0"
         android:fromYScale="1.0"
         android:pivotX="50%"
         android:pivotY="50%"
         android:toXScale="0.0"
         android:toYScale="0.0" />

    <alpha
         android:duration="300"
         android:fromAlpha="1.0"
         android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
         android:toAlpha="0.0" />

</set>
```

Is it possible to change the background color in this file or I need to do it somewhere else?

This file is called center_pop_up_exit and I'm using it when user clicks a button which listener is:

```
View.OnClickListener noAccountHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SignUpFragment signUpFragment = new SignUpFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left_enter, R.anim.center_pop_up_exit, 0, R.anim.center_pop_up_exit);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.log_in_fragment_container, signUpFragment, "SignUpFragment");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
};
```

Comment: How and where do you apply this `xml` file?

Comment: I've just edited my question to show you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do it in the anim xml. However, I managed to get the effect I wanted by using TransitionDrawable. So first of all, I created a xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- The drawables used here can be solid colors, gradients, shapes, images, etc. -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transp_black" />
</transition>
```

After that I need to set this file as the background of the view I want the shade on (in my case, this is my fragment's container):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/shade"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/transition_drawable"/>
```

Then I get the view, get the view's background and make the transition:

```
shadeLayout = postMeasurementsFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.shade);
TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable = (TransitionDrawable)shadeLayout.getBackground();
transitionDrawable.startTransition(200);
```

Finally, after triggering the transition I can make my fragment transaction:

```
Fragment fragment = new PostMeasurementFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ((PostActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up_enter,0,0,R.anim.slide_down_exit);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.modal_measurement_container, fragment, "PostMeasurementFragment");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

plus: if you need to revert that transition, you get the view and the view's background again and make another transition:

```
TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable = (TransitionDrawable)shadeLayout.getBackground();
transitionDrawable.reverseTransition(200);
```

In my case I use that before popBackStack. That's it!